# Group arrays by key value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I have a problem approaching an issue i have, i need to group `arrays` by `key` `value`

I have 3 foreach functions

```
    foreach ($report_phonecall as $key=>$value) {
        $phonecalls[$value['datum']] =  $value['broj'];
    };
    foreach ($report_meeting as $key=>$value) {
        $meetings[$value['datum']] =  $value['broj'];
    }
    foreach ($report_notes as $key=>$value) {
        $notes[$value['datum']] =  $value['broj'];
    }
```

That give me `array`

```
   $phonecall = Array ( [2016-07-13] => 2 [2016-07-14] => 1 [2016-07-19] =>1 ) 
   $meetings = Array ( [2016-07-13] => 1 [2016-07-14] => 1 ) 
   $notes = Array ( [2016-07-19] => 1 )
```

I need to merge them into 1 `array` foreach date like this

```
Array(2016-07-13 => array([phonecalls]=>2, [meetings]=>1, [notes]=>0)) 2016-07-14 => array([phonecalls]=>1, [meetings]=> 1, [notes]=>0).... etc
```

I want to group/sort them by key value.

Going by

```
    $group_reports[$value[key]] = $value['broj'][$phonecalls][$meetings][$notes]
```

Im not sure how to define it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code for merge array

```
$finalArr = array();
foreach($phonecall as $key=>$val){
    $finalArr[$key]['phonecalls'] = $val;
    $finalArr[$key]['meetings'] = 0;
    $finalArr[$key]['notes'] = 0;
}

foreach($meetings as $key=>$val){
    if(array_key_exists($key, $finalArr)){
        $finalArr[$key]['meetings'] = $val;
    } else {
        $finalArr[$key]['phonecalls'] = 0;
        $finalArr[$key]['meetings'] = $val;
        $finalArr[$key]['notes'] = 0;
    }
}

foreach($notes as $key=>$val){
    if(array_key_exists($key, $finalArr)){
        $finalArr[$key]['notes'] = $val;
    } else {
        $finalArr[$key]['phonecalls'] = 0;
        $finalArr[$key]['meetings'] = 0;
        $finalArr[$key]['notes'] = $val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about like this?

```
$phonecall = ['2016-07-13' => 2, '2016-07-14' => 1, '2016-07-19' => 1];
$meetings = ['2016-07-13' => 1, '2016-07-14' => 1];
$notes = ['2016-07-19' => 1];

// Get *all* possible dates
$keys = array_unique(array_keys($phonecall+$meetings+$notes));

foreach($keys as $key) {
    $final[$key] = [
            'phonecalls' => isset($phonecall[$key]) ? $phonecall[$key] : 0,
            'meetings'   => isset($meetings[$key])  ? $meetings[$key]  : 0,
            'notes'      => isset($notes[$key])     ? $notes[$key]     : 0
    ];
}
```

Comment: best possible answer among all. +10